# Appium Java sendText(); cannot send letter "a" and "b"

Tags: java, appium, appium-android, appium-desktop

this is my first time asking questing here. Here is my code

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText")).get(0).sendKeys(sometext);
```

, i have tested it will all character.

Everything is working fine except for the letter "a" and "b". It cannot input those letter. It also doesn't show any error. Really frustrated by this issue.

For extra details, i also use adb shell input text to test various edittext on various apps, adb shell input text "any character work" except adb input text "a" and "b". It doesn't show any error but those letter just doesn't want to show. I'm using my personal android phone for this testing. The android version is 6.0. It is produced by local company in my country. This problem doesn’t occur while i’m using real android phone in version 4.2.2

Comment: First, you should not combine (chain) the actions.  Assign the element to a variable.  Clear the web element (AndroidElement or MobileElement).  Then sendkeys.  Appium does sometimes have problems with sendkeys and there are various offered solutions if you'll search for them.  It's also possible that whatever edittext object you are working with specifically does not accept "a" or "b" for some reason, you'd need to elaborate on the situation to know for sure.

Comment: Hi, thankyou for your advice, i've tried that but still not working. For extra details, i also use adb shell input text to test various edittext on various apps, adb shell input text "any character work" except adb input text "a" and "b". It doesn't show any error but those letter just doesn't want to show. I'm using my personal android phone for this testing. The android version is 6.0. It is produced by local company in my country. This problem doesn’t occur while i’m using real android phone in version 4.2.2.

Comment: Are you only sending a single character or are you saying if you sent "cat" it only shows "ct"

Comment: yes, it will only show "ct"

Comment: You said this is working okay with a physical device, but failing on the emulator.  Have you tried manually entering the text in the emulator instead of using Appium automation?  Does it allow it to be entered manually?

Comment: It's working on one physical device, but not another.

Comment: It's like what Mike Collins said, I only test it on physical device. Testing manually is working fine.

Comment: My question was does it work on the emulated device when you MANUALLY try to enter values as opposed to using Appium/sendKeys?  If you can use the mouse and manually select all the characters on the on-screen keyboard, but your scrip fails, then it points to a defect in Appium (perhaps) but if you cannot type "a" or "b" with the mouse manually but any other key works, then it would appear to be a problem with the emulator.  The process of debugging things like this is a process of elimination.

Comment: To add to my previous comment, if the script runs on a real device, it's much more likely that there's a problem with the emulator.  Consider resetting/clearing the emulator or creating a new one.